# What is the condition for Morera's theorem to be true?

Tags: complex-analysis, connectedness

The answer could be chosen from

a) simply connected domain

b)connected domain

c)no conditions(true for any complex domain)

I chose c because the theorem(in our textbook, at least) does not imply anything about the domain. The only assumption made in the statement was f being a continuous function. But some other version of this theorem does say the domain has to be simply connected. So I'm really confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the answer is C.

Morera theorem does not require anything from the domain. Only its inverse (in some sense) where you want to deduce that some integrals vanish (essentially the Cauchy integral theorem) does.

So we can see that Morera theorem's condition is not necessary for holomorphic functions, as not all holomorphic functions satisfy it on their domain, e.g. $w=\log(z)$. They only satisfy it on simply-connected subdomains of their domain of definition.